# How do I specify "everything except the top row" as a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have Sheet1, which is automatically being updated via form entries.

I'm making Sheet2, which is a self-sorting version of Sheet1 (it intended to be a copy of Sheet1 but sorted by a column). Ideally I would just auto-sort everything on Sheet1 and not even make Sheet2, but it appears I can't.

If I attempt to select all of Sheet1 as a range, Google Docs will return `Sheet1!1:102`. So if I get more than 102 entries on Sheet1, Sheet2 apparently will not include them.

If instead I select the columns on Sheet1, I get`Sheet1!C:J`. That's better. But I want to exclude the very top row. Otherwise it will sort the column title as if it were just another value.

Is there an elegant way to specify this as a range?

Or do I have to manually pluck out the top row with the filter function or something?

Answer (score 36):

There's an easy way. For example, for a sum, you can specify it like this:

```
=SUM(G2:G)
```

So basically, specify the first cell you want, then the name of the column. That way, you can skip as many rows as you want.

Comment: Keep in mind you need to put this total somewhere other than in the column you are summing or you will get a circular dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been answered elsewhere, but my particular search query (google sheet ignore first row) when trying to solve this issue surfaced this article as the first result.  As that's the case, I decided to leave an updated response once I solved this issue for myself.

If you select the row (or rows) that you'd like to keep unaffected by your sort, then right click, there's a context option near the bottom of the popup menu called "View more row actions".

The first sub-option therein is "Freeze up to row x" where x is the row you have selected, or the first of the rows you have selected.